# How does Windows launch packaged Apps

Tags: windows, msix, appx

How exactly does Windows launch packaged (appx or msix) apps?

For example, consider the settings app (ImmersiveControlPanel, lives in C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel) on Windows 11

```
    <Applications>
        <Application
            Id="microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel"
            Executable="SystemSettings.exe"
            EntryPoint="AppObject.EntryPoint">
            [...]
        </Application>
    </Applications>
```

Its Appxmanifest specifies the executable and a class id as entry point.

What exactly does happen between searching and clicking the settings app in the startmenu or invoking with e.g. `ms-settings:settings` and the settings app window showing up?

It magically works, but i failed to find any documentation that goes a bit more into detail.

Comment: OS implementation details are not documented and subject to change without notice.